# Fabric 1.15.2 My Loot Table Isn't Working

Tags: json, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

Hello I'm new to minecraft Modding I use fabric just because it's easier

My loot table for my block is not working can you help ?

My code:

```
    {
        "type": "minecraft:block",
        "pools": 
        [
            {
                "rolls": 1,
                "entries":
                [
                    {
                        "type": "minecraft:item",
                        "name": "testmod:fabric_block"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

my file is located in: `data/testmod/loot_tables/block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in `data/testmod/loot_tables/blocks`